# How do I inject multiple instances of a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IService<T>  
{  
    void DoSomething(T obj)  
}
```

And several implementations:

```
public class ServiceA : IService<A>
{  
    public void DoSomething(A a)  
} 
public class ServiceB : IService<B>  
{  
    public void DoSomething(B b)  
}
```

How can I inject all the instances that implement `IService<T>` in the constructor of a consuming class?

Comment: why don't you create non generic version of IService if you don't care about generic parameter anyway?

Comment: the IService DoSomething method has to have different type parameters in the different implementations and has to be called in the consumer service.

Comment: It is possible to inject a collection of a certain type e.g. `IEnumerable<IService>` will get all `IService`.  I'm not sure if this works with open generics though e.g. `IEnumerable<IService<>>` but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject `IServiceProvider` into your consumer and then use a resolving method like `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService<T>>()` to resolve the registered generic service.

It violates some form of DI principles but is the way to get the correct implementation inside the method. Otherwise you would have to create a whole class (`Consumer<T>`) that is registered with a factory that does a similar call to set up `Consumer<T>`.